# innerHtml no funciona paginacion

Tags: javascript

Estoy creando una paginacion solo con JavaScript sin usar Jquery pero quiero inserar los botones de la paginacion dependiendo de la cantidad de elementos y la cantidad de elementos por pagina, el innerHTML de la linea 34 no inserta los botones en la pagina si reviso el valor de divButtons por consola esta correcto pero no aparce en la pagina.

```js
// Global Variables
var itemsPerPage = 10;
var list = document.getElementsByClassName('student-list');
var items = document.getElementsByClassName('student-item');
var actualPage = 1;
var divButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("pagination");
var index;
var message;

// Count the numbrer of items in the list
var getNumberOfItems = function () {
  var numbrerOfItems = items.length;
  return (numbrerOfItems);
}
// Generating rhe number of pages
var getNumberOfPages = function () {
  var numberOfPages = parseInt(getNumberOfItems() / itemsPerPage);
  if ( getNumberOfItems() % itemsPerPage > 0 ){
    numberOfPages += 1;
  }
  return numberOfPages;
}
// add the navigations buttons
var addButtons = function (activePage) {
  message = "<ul>";
  for (var i = 0; i < getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
      message += "<li><a ";
      if(activePage === (i +1)){
        message += "class = 'active' ";
      }
      message += "href='#' onclick = 'changePage(" + (i + 1) + ")'>" + ( i +1 ) + "</a></li>";
  }
  message += "</ul>";
  divButtons.innerHTML(message);
}

var hideItems = function () {
  for (var i = 0; i < getNumberOfItems(); i++) {
    items[i].style.display = "none";

  }

}

function showItemsByPage (page) {
  for (var i = 0; i <= itemsPerPage - 1; i++) {
    index = page * itemsPerPage - itemsPerPage  + i;
    items[index].style.display = "block";
  }
}

function changePage (number) {
  document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", hideItems());
  document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", showItemsByPage(number));
  document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", addButtons(number));
}

changePage(1);
```

```css
body{
  background-color: #e1f1f6;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #222;
}

.page{
  margin: 50px auto;
  width: 70%;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 50px;
}

.page-header{
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
  .page-header h2{
    float: left;
    font-size: 22px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #555;
  }

  .page-header .student-search{
    float: right;
  }

    .page-header .student-search input{
      border-radius: 5px;
      border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
      padding: 8px 15px;
      font-size: 14px;
    }

    .page-header .student-search button{
      border-radius: 5px;
      border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
      padding: 8px 15px;
      font-size: 14px;
      background-color: #4ba6c3;
      color: #fff
    }

.student-list{}

  .student-item{
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
    padding: 0 0 20px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  }

    .student-details{
      width: 50%;
      float: left;
    }

      .student-details .avatar{
        width: 40px;
        height: auto;
        border-radius: 20px;
        float: left;
        margin-right: 14px
      }

      .student-details h3{
        margin: 4px 0 2px 0;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #4ba6c3;
      }

      .student-details .email{
        color: #888;
        font-size: 14px;
      }


    .joined-details{
      width: 50%;
      float: left;
      text-align: right;
    }

      .joined-details .date{
        margin-top: 15px;
        display: block;
        font-size: 14px;
        color: #999;
      }

  .student-item:last-child{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border-bottom: none;
  }

.pagination{
  margin: 40px 0 0 0;
  text-align: center;
}
 
  .pagination li{
    display: inline;
  }

    .pagination li a{
      border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
      border-radius: 5px;
      padding: 3px 8px;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #4ba6c3;
    }

    .pagination li a.active,
    .pagination li a:hover{
      background-color: #4ba6c3;
      color: #fff;
    }
.hidenItems{
  display: none;
}
.showItems{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <title>Students</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/design.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="page">
      <div class="page-header cf">
        <h2>Students</h2>
      </div>
      <ul class="student-list">
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/67.jpg">
                <h3>iboya vat</h3>
                <span class="email">iboya.vat@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 07/15/15</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/75.jpg">
                <h3>aapo niskanen</h3>
                <span class="email">aapo.niskanen@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 06/15/12</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/34.jpg">
                <h3>phillip cox</h3>
                <span class="email">phillip.cox@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 09/11/14</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/38.jpg">
                <h3>zilda moreira</h3>
                <span class="email">zilda.moreira@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 07/15/15</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/23.jpg">
                <h3>lilou le gall</h3>
                <span class="email">lilou.le gall@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 06/16/13</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/94.jpg">
                <h3>lucy hall</h3>
                <span class="email">lucy.hall@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 09/11/16</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/24.jpg">
                <h3>mark colin</h3>
                <span class="email">mark.colin@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 01/14/14</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/14.jpg">
                <h3>sara alves</h3>
                <span class="email">sara.alves@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 07/19/16</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/49.jpg">
                <h3>ramon macrae</h3>
                <span class="email">ramon.macrae@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 05/13/12</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/15.jpg">
                <h3>connor taylor</h3>
                <span class="email">connor.taylor@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 05/18/14</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/11.jpg">
                <h3>aymeric morel</h3>
                <span class="email">aymeric.morel@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 06/13/13</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/49.jpg">
                <h3>lorenz otto</h3>
                <span class="email">lorenz.otto@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 05/11/14</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/29.jpg">
                <h3>karl williamson</h3>
                <span class="email">karl.williamson@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 01/12/14</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/34.jpg">
                <h3>ouassim heering</h3>
                <span class="email">ouassim.heering@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 01/18/12</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/91.jpg">
                <h3>roberto molina</h3>
                <span class="email">roberto.molina@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 06/13/15</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/28.jpg">
                <h3>jordan hubert</h3>
                <span class="email">jordan.hubert@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 06/13/15</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/29.jpg">
                <h3>melvin baker</h3>
                <span class="email">melvin.baker@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 09/18/14</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/26.jpg">
                <h3>everett gordon</h3>
                <span class="email">everett.gordon@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 06/17/15</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/82.jpg">
                <h3>aiden ma</h3>
                <span class="email">aiden.ma@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 07/18/12</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/62.jpg">
                <h3>florent gerard</h3>
                <span class="email">florent.gerard@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 02/12/13</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/96.jpg">
                <h3>amber chen</h3>
                <span class="email">amber.chen@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 07/12/12</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/9.jpg">
                <h3>alexandra davies</h3>
                <span class="email">alexandra.davies@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 05/11/13</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/57.jpg">
                <h3>sergio cole</h3>
                <span class="email">sergio.cole@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 02/17/15</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/98.jpg">
                <h3>edgar dixon</h3>
                <span class="email">edgar.dixon@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 06/17/11</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/94.jpg">
                <h3>kirk myers</h3>
                <span class="email">kirk.myers@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 09/17/15</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/28.jpg">
                <h3>ani hesseling</h3>
                <span class="email">ani.hesseling@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 08/14/16</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/24.jpg">
                <h3>victoire bonnet</h3>
                <span class="email">victoire.bonnet@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 05/13/16</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/44.jpg">
                <h3>marcos morales</h3>
                <span class="email">marcos.morales@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 01/12/12</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/75.jpg">
                <h3>nils neumann</h3>
                <span class="email">nils.neumann@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 03/11/12</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/86.jpg">
                <h3>emily harrison</h3>
                <span class="email">emily.harrison@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 07/18/15</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/41.jpg">
                <h3>matthew fortin</h3>
                <span class="email">matthew.fortin@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 03/18/15</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/32.jpg">
                <h3>charlotte steward</h3>
                <span class="email">charlotte.steward@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 02/18/11</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/3.jpg">
                <h3>marceau rodriguez</h3>
                <span class="email">marceau.rodriguez@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 07/13/14</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/91.jpg">
                <h3>hudson anderson</h3>
                <span class="email">hudson.anderson@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 09/12/15</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/33.jpg">
                <h3>warren phillips</h3>
                <span class="email">warren.phillips@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 01/11/12</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/41.jpg">
                <h3>leo niva</h3>
                <span class="email">leo.niva@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 09/14/15</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/3.jpg">
                <h3>hani prevoo</h3>
                <span class="email">hani.prevoo@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 01/11/15</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/79.jpg">
                <h3>veronica rodriguez</h3>
                <span class="email">veronica.rodriguez@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 07/17/12</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/41.jpg">
                <h3>ginestal das neves</h3>
                <span class="email">ginestal.das neves@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 06/19/12</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/63.jpg">
                <h3>devon barnes</h3>
                <span class="email">devon.barnes@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 09/19/14</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/55.jpg">
                <h3>brennan pierce</h3>
                <span class="email">brennan.pierce@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 05/15/14</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/35.jpg">
                <h3>zachary singh</h3>
                <span class="email">zachary.singh@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 05/19/11</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/35.jpg">
                <h3>arlo harris</h3>
                <span class="email">arlo.harris@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 07/12/15</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/60.jpg">
                <h3>hannah ginnish</h3>
                <span class="email">hannah.ginnish@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 05/17/14</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/95.jpg">
                <h3>goos brunt</h3>
                <span class="email">goos.brunt@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 09/15/12</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/91.jpg">
                <h3>eduard riedel</h3>
                <span class="email">eduard.riedel@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 06/12/15</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/42.jpg">
                <h3>geesken jekel</h3>
                <span class="email">geesken.jekel@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 02/12/13</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/54.jpg">
                <h3>dolores ryan</h3>
                <span class="email">dolores.ryan@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 06/17/16</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/49.jpg">
                <h3>steven rogers</h3>
                <span class="email">steven.rogers@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 01/18/11</span>
           </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="pagination">

      </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src= "js/scripts.js">

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al ejeecutar tu propio código en la pregunta, puedo ver en la consola:

> Uncaught TypeError: divButtons.innerHTML is not a function

Eso ocurre porque estás llamando a innerHTML como si fuera una función, cuando lo que tienes que hacer es asignarlo como una propiedad:

```
divButtons.innerHTML = message;
```

Además, `divButtons` se obtiene con `getElementsByClassName` por lo que es un array de elementos y no un elmeento en sí, y debes seleccionar el primero:

```
divButtons[0].innerHTML = message;
```

Y ahora ya no da ese error:

```js
// Global Variables
var itemsPerPage = 10;
var list = document.getElementsByClassName('student-list');
var items = document.getElementsByClassName('student-item');
var actualPage = 1;
var divButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("pagination");
var index;
var message;

// Count the numbrer of items in the list
var getNumberOfItems = function () {
  var numbrerOfItems = items.length;
  return (numbrerOfItems);
}
// Generating rhe number of pages
var getNumberOfPages = function () {
  var numberOfPages = parseInt(getNumberOfItems() / itemsPerPage);
  if ( getNumberOfItems() % itemsPerPage > 0 ){
    numberOfPages += 1;
  }
  return numberOfPages;
}
// add the navigations buttons
var addButtons = function (activePage) {
  message = "<ul>";
  for (var i = 0; i < getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
      message += "<li><a ";
      if(activePage === (i +1)){
        message += "class = 'active' ";
      }
      message += "href='#' onclick = 'changePage(" + (i + 1) + ")'>" + ( i +1 ) + "</a></li>";
  }
  message += "</ul>";
  divButtons[0].innerHTML = message;
}

var hideItems = function () {
  for (var i = 0; i < getNumberOfItems(); i++) {
    items[i].style.display = "none";

  }

}

function showItemsByPage (page) {
  for (var i = 0; i <= itemsPerPage - 1; i++) {
    index = page * itemsPerPage - itemsPerPage  + i;
    items[index].style.display = "block";
  }
}

function changePage (number) {
  document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", hideItems());
  document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", showItemsByPage(number));
  document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", addButtons(number));
}

changePage(1);
```

```css
body{
  background-color: #e1f1f6;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #222;
}

.page{
  margin: 50px auto;
  width: 70%;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 50px;
}

.page-header{
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
  .page-header h2{
    float: left;
    font-size: 22px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #555;
  }

  .page-header .student-search{
    float: right;
  }

    .page-header .student-search input{
      border-radius: 5px;
      border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
      padding: 8px 15px;
      font-size: 14px;
    }

    .page-header .student-search button{
      border-radius: 5px;
      border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
      padding: 8px 15px;
      font-size: 14px;
      background-color: #4ba6c3;
      color: #fff
    }

.student-list{}

  .student-item{
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
    padding: 0 0 20px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  }

    .student-details{
      width: 50%;
      float: left;
    }

      .student-details .avatar{
        width: 40px;
        height: auto;
        border-radius: 20px;
        float: left;
        margin-right: 14px
      }

      .student-details h3{
        margin: 4px 0 2px 0;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #4ba6c3;
      }

      .student-details .email{
        color: #888;
        font-size: 14px;
      }


    .joined-details{
      width: 50%;
      float: left;
      text-align: right;
    }

      .joined-details .date{
        margin-top: 15px;
        display: block;
        font-size: 14px;
        color: #999;
      }

  .student-item:last-child{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border-bottom: none;
  }

.pagination{
  margin: 40px 0 0 0;
  text-align: center;
}
 
  .pagination li{
    display: inline;
  }

    .pagination li a{
      border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
      border-radius: 5px;
      padding: 3px 8px;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #4ba6c3;
    }

    .pagination li a.active,
    .pagination li a:hover{
      background-color: #4ba6c3;
      color: #fff;
    }
.hidenItems{
  display: none;
}
.showItems{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <title>Students</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/design.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="page">
      <div class="page-header cf">
        <h2>Students</h2>
      </div>
      <ul class="student-list">
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/67.jpg">
                <h3>iboya vat</h3>
                <span class="email">iboya.vat@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 07/15/15</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/75.jpg">
                <h3>aapo niskanen</h3>
                <span class="email">aapo.niskanen@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 06/15/12</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/34.jpg">
                <h3>phillip cox</h3>
                <span class="email">phillip.cox@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 09/11/14</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/38.jpg">
                <h3>zilda moreira</h3>
                <span class="email">zilda.moreira@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 07/15/15</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/23.jpg">
                <h3>lilou le gall</h3>
                <span class="email">lilou.le gall@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 06/16/13</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/94.jpg">
                <h3>lucy hall</h3>
                <span class="email">lucy.hall@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 09/11/16</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/24.jpg">
                <h3>mark colin</h3>
                <span class="email">mark.colin@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 01/14/14</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/14.jpg">
                <h3>sara alves</h3>
                <span class="email">sara.alves@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 07/19/16</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/49.jpg">
                <h3>ramon macrae</h3>
                <span class="email">ramon.macrae@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 05/13/12</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/15.jpg">
                <h3>connor taylor</h3>
                <span class="email">connor.taylor@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 05/18/14</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/11.jpg">
                <h3>aymeric morel</h3>
                <span class="email">aymeric.morel@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 06/13/13</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/49.jpg">
                <h3>lorenz otto</h3>
                <span class="email">lorenz.otto@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 05/11/14</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/29.jpg">
                <h3>karl williamson</h3>
                <span class="email">karl.williamson@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 01/12/14</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/34.jpg">
                <h3>ouassim heering</h3>
                <span class="email">ouassim.heering@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 01/18/12</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/91.jpg">
                <h3>roberto molina</h3>
                <span class="email">roberto.molina@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 06/13/15</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/28.jpg">
                <h3>jordan hubert</h3>
                <span class="email">jordan.hubert@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 06/13/15</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/29.jpg">
                <h3>melvin baker</h3>
                <span class="email">melvin.baker@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 09/18/14</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/26.jpg">
                <h3>everett gordon</h3>
                <span class="email">everett.gordon@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 06/17/15</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/82.jpg">
                <h3>aiden ma</h3>
                <span class="email">aiden.ma@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 07/18/12</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/62.jpg">
                <h3>florent gerard</h3>
                <span class="email">florent.gerard@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 02/12/13</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/96.jpg">
                <h3>amber chen</h3>
                <span class="email">amber.chen@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 07/12/12</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/9.jpg">
                <h3>alexandra davies</h3>
                <span class="email">alexandra.davies@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 05/11/13</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/57.jpg">
                <h3>sergio cole</h3>
                <span class="email">sergio.cole@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 02/17/15</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/98.jpg">
                <h3>edgar dixon</h3>
                <span class="email">edgar.dixon@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 06/17/11</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/94.jpg">
                <h3>kirk myers</h3>
                <span class="email">kirk.myers@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 09/17/15</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/28.jpg">
                <h3>ani hesseling</h3>
                <span class="email">ani.hesseling@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 08/14/16</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/24.jpg">
                <h3>victoire bonnet</h3>
                <span class="email">victoire.bonnet@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 05/13/16</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/44.jpg">
                <h3>marcos morales</h3>
                <span class="email">marcos.morales@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 01/12/12</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/75.jpg">
                <h3>nils neumann</h3>
                <span class="email">nils.neumann@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 03/11/12</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/86.jpg">
                <h3>emily harrison</h3>
                <span class="email">emily.harrison@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 07/18/15</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/41.jpg">
                <h3>matthew fortin</h3>
                <span class="email">matthew.fortin@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 03/18/15</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/32.jpg">
                <h3>charlotte steward</h3>
                <span class="email">charlotte.steward@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 02/18/11</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/3.jpg">
                <h3>marceau rodriguez</h3>
                <span class="email">marceau.rodriguez@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 07/13/14</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/91.jpg">
                <h3>hudson anderson</h3>
                <span class="email">hudson.anderson@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 09/12/15</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/33.jpg">
                <h3>warren phillips</h3>
                <span class="email">warren.phillips@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 01/11/12</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/41.jpg">
                <h3>leo niva</h3>
                <span class="email">leo.niva@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 09/14/15</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/3.jpg">
                <h3>hani prevoo</h3>
                <span class="email">hani.prevoo@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 01/11/15</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/79.jpg">
                <h3>veronica rodriguez</h3>
                <span class="email">veronica.rodriguez@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 07/17/12</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/41.jpg">
                <h3>ginestal das neves</h3>
                <span class="email">ginestal.das neves@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 06/19/12</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/63.jpg">
                <h3>devon barnes</h3>
                <span class="email">devon.barnes@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 09/19/14</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/55.jpg">
                <h3>brennan pierce</h3>
                <span class="email">brennan.pierce@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 05/15/14</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/35.jpg">
                <h3>zachary singh</h3>
                <span class="email">zachary.singh@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 05/19/11</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/35.jpg">
                <h3>arlo harris</h3>
                <span class="email">arlo.harris@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 07/12/15</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/60.jpg">
                <h3>hannah ginnish</h3>
                <span class="email">hannah.ginnish@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 05/17/14</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/95.jpg">
                <h3>goos brunt</h3>
                <span class="email">goos.brunt@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 09/15/12</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/91.jpg">
                <h3>eduard riedel</h3>
                <span class="email">eduard.riedel@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 06/12/15</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/42.jpg">
                <h3>geesken jekel</h3>
                <span class="email">geesken.jekel@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 02/12/13</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/54.jpg">
                <h3>dolores ryan</h3>
                <span class="email">dolores.ryan@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 06/17/16</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/49.jpg">
                <h3>steven rogers</h3>
                <span class="email">steven.rogers@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 01/18/11</span>
           </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="pagination">

      </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src= "js/scripts.js">

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias porque debo colocar [0] en el divButtons solo estoy seleccionando un elemento no entiendo porque me devuelve un arrray

Comment: El propio nombre lo indica getElement**s**ByClassName: un arrray de elementos, y no un único elemento como con getElementById. `getElementsByClassName` devuelve una lista/array de elementos, otras variables (como `list` o `items`) no dan error porque las estás utilizando dentro de un bucle (ej: `items[i].style.display = "none";`) si te fijas, se indica un índice que no se estaba haciendo para el caso de `divButtons`

Comment: Muchas gracias apenas estoy empezando en la programacion y me fue de gran utilidad tu ayuda