# Tabla HTML -Barra de paginacion numérica/ paginación -Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Deseo colocar debajo de una tabla html una barra de paginación numérica. Debe ser con Javascript. No puede haber nada jquery.

Esta es mi tabla, la cual la voy relleando con un script(van entrado datos de una base de datos)

```
<table id="tbl_usuario_list" class="table table-hover">
    <tr>

            <td><b>Índice<b></td>
            <td><b>#ID del usuario<b></td>
            <td><b>Nombre<b></td>
            <td><b>Link de su foto<b></td>      
    </tr>
</table>
```

Pues bien, he encontrado el siguiente código para paginación con JS

[Aqui esta mi referencia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/20617/innerhtml-no-funciona-paginacion)

Él tiene una tabla con id, igual que en mi código, pero él tiene un

```
<li class="student-item cf">

 //....
</li>
```

En cada usuario
He intentando poner esto en mi tabla

```
       <div class="container">
<h3>Lista de Usuários</h3>
<table id="tbl_usuario_list" class="table table-hover">
    <tr>
       <li class="student-item cf">
            <td><b>Índice<b></td>
            <td><b>#ID del usuario<b></td>
            <td><b>Nombre<b></td>
            <td><b>Link de su foto<b></td>
         </li>  
    </tr>
</table>
```

Y cargar el js de nuestro compañero @AlvaroMontoro

Y me da siguiente error cuando voy a inspeccionar elemento->consola

```
Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
at bootstrap.min.js:6

scripts.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Sabéis como puedo hacer la paginación en js para mi tabla?

Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap requiere de JQuery. Por lo que tienes que cargar los archivos JQuery antes que los de bootstrap.

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script> <!--Primero jquery-->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> <!--Segundo bootstrap-->
```

[Bootstrap's Javascript requires jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22658015/bootstrap-wont-detect-jquery-1-11-0-uncaught-error-bootstraps-javascript-re)

Comment: Hola. Acabo de poner tu texto en el head de mi html. Pero ahora me da mas errores. Como este: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)  Yo creo que es porque no enlazo bien el codigo con mi tabla no?